# Что не так в коде JS? (Задачка на подсчет гласных и согласных)

Tags: javascript, методы, split, match

Решил написать отрывок кода, который выводит innerHTML количество гласных и согласных в строке input, в консоли показывает xerere.split, не знаю в чем проблема.

код:

```js
    var pok = document.getElementById("Pokaz"); 
    pok.addEventListener('click', matchZ);

    function matchZ () {
        var place1 = document.getElementById('pl1');  
        var place2 = document.getElementById('pl2');  
        var xerere = document.getElementById('stringPlace'); 
        xerere.toString();
        var x = xerere.split();
        var glassny = x.match(/[аоиеёэыуюя]/gi);
        var soglassny = x.match(/[бвгджзйклмнпрстфхцчшщ]/gi);

        place1.innerHTML = 'Количество гласных :'+glassny;
        place2.innerHTML = 'Количество согласных :'+soglassny;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Не совсем понятно: что в переменной "xerere"?

Код поправил на свое усмотрение, может пригодится для сравнительного анализа и понимания:

```js
var input = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("input"));
input.type = "text";
input.id = "stringPlace";

var button = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("button"));
button.id = "Pokaz";
button.textContent = "Click";

var output1 = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("p"));
output1.id = "pl1";

var output2 = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("p"));
output2.id = "pl2";

var pok = document.getElementById("Pokaz");
pok.addEventListener("click", matchZ);

function matchZ() {
  var place1 = document.getElementById("pl1");
  var place2 = document.getElementById("pl2");
  var xerere = document.getElementById("stringPlace");
  var value = xerere.value;
  var glassny = value.match(/[аоиеёэыуюя]/gi);
  var soglassny = value.match(/[бвгджзйклмнпрстфхцчшщ]/gi);

  place1.innerHTML = "Количество гласных : " + (glassny ? glassny.length : 0);
  place2.innerHTML =
    "Количество согласных : " + (soglassny ? soglassny.length : 0);
}
```

Можно запустить по [ссылке](https://codepen.io/a-silent/pen/gOOOgBz).